# Points on map very uniform

Tags: coordinate-system, csv

I'm having some issues adding in some foodplant data from BSBI. I've added it in as a CSV but it's showing on the map as the below. I'm unsure if this is correct as it all looks very uniform and some points are located in the sea! The data and the basemap both share the same CRS (EPSG: 4326). The map also looks very horizontal too, which doesn't look great.

Can you lend a hand with that?

[image]

Comment: This could be due by rounding the coordinate (either intentionally to not disclose an exact location or as a mistake somewhere in the handling of data). To give you a more detailled answer we need more information.  Did the point are roughly at the right place ? Could you share an extract of your data (the coordinate of a few point will do) ? Witch software (in witch version) are you using for display ? ...

Comment: Okay. I'm using version 3.28.4 here are a few examples:                                                                                                  54.98128262 -8.547406021
54.89206078 -8.39035382
54.98188471 -8.391223979
55.0717073 -8.392098994

Comment: Some points look roughly correct, whereas others are in the middle of the sea which is definitely not correct!

Comment: As a side note, please don't ask two questions in the same post.

Answer (score 4):

According to https://bsbi.org/maps-and-data they record the plant occurences on the national grid. So most probably the points are the grid cell centers.

Grid cells that contain a tiny land area and lots of sea will have their center in the sea.

edit: as for the second question, that is a matter of map projection. maybe change the projection (in the lower right corner of QGIS) to EPSG:3034 or EPSG:3857 (EPSG:3857 is the projection probably used in your OpenStreetMap basemap, so there will be no stretching errors in the basemap)  and see if it looks better. See the QGIS docs at https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html .